# Recreating array in JS somehow ends up binding multiple keydown events

Tags: javascript, jquery

so here is my weird problem.

I have a simple "player / editor of images" where you can  basically move through pictures and rotate and or delete them. The player iterates through json list of images and creates a sequential array (0,1,2,3,...) so I can keep track of positions. Left arrow key and Right arrow key are assigned to movements +1 or -1 sent to sequential array to retrieve image location.

All great. I have assigned D to be a delete action that takes the picture id and sends an $.post to remove image from DB, remove from the json list and then recreate the sequential array from the update json list. Now here is the kicker. Once I press the D i remove the item from json list, i update DB, now upon recreating the sequential array my next and back actions (left arrow key, right arrow key) start adding +1 for everytime i press the D button.

So in short. When i start fresh the numbers go 1, 2, 3, 4, 5... When i press delete the numbers continue as 7, 9, 11, 13... If i press delete again it will continue at 16, 19, 21, 24,... and so on... I have no idea where this is rebinding... or am I missing something?

Heres the code

```
var items = {"a1046229":{"id":"1046229","file_path":"\/2013\/05\/2177\/11\/600x500\/92909a26e6b3cd2ad96d4c6977bd9e74.jpg","raw_path":"\/2013\/05\/2177\/11\/92909a26e6b3cd2ad96d4c6977bd9e74.jpg","pos":1},"a1046230":{"id":"1046230","file_path":"\/2013\/05\/2177\/11\/600x500\/edd7996f61c135764c2a9e19444c308b.jpg","raw_path":"\/2013\/05\/2177\/11\/edd7996f61c135764c2a9e19444c308b.jpg","pos":2}.....
```

Heres the function that creates sequential array

```
function _prepare_images() {
    if (!imgList.length) {
        var name, pos = 0;
        for (name in items) {
            imgList.push({
                id: items[name].id,
                info: items[name],
                pos: pos++
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Once i press D i remove from the actual list

```
delete items['a' + image.data('id')];
imgList.length = 0;
```

So now when I press next or previous the imgList gets recreated... but starts skipping...

I am clueless. Can anybody please help

Comment: Just a note. You should always look in the preview if your code is correctly formated so that it is not displayed in one line. Otherwise it is really difficult to read it.

Comment: t.niese thank you! I'm tired as hell so I typed too fast :)

Comment: now i had time to reread the question, but it is still not clear to me. What in your code corresponds to the `number` that is increasing? When your press `D` the delete is called and then a post returning `items` ?